# Inside sudo, environment variables are not set when command is inline versus calling a second script

Tags: environment-variables, ksh, sudo, su

I am running a korn shell script as root and need to sudo to a different user (oracle) to execute some commands and I need access to the environment variables set in .profile.

I am seeing different behavior if I call a 2nd script to execute the commands versus executing them inline.

Here is a simple test to demonstrate. This works and displays the $ORACLE_HOME environment variable:

```
sudo su - oracle -s /bin/ksh -c "/home/u6vzbes/upgrade/get_oracle_home_test.ksh"
```

Where the called script is just this:

```
#!/bin/ksh
echo 'Called from script - ORACLE_HOME is '  ${ORACLE_HOME}
```

But this DOES NOT work, with the $ORACLE_HOME environment variable being blank:

```
sudo su - oracle -s /bin/ksh -c "
 echo 'Called from sudo - Oracle home is ${ORACLE_HOME}'
"
```

Why do these two work differently? I would prefer to execute commands inline rather than have a second script as I will need to sudo to oracle multiple times throughout the root script. FYI, the environment variable is set in the .profile of the oracle user.

Comment: I'm not sure I was 100% clear. When the echo is in a separate script, the variable is displayed fine. But when I have the echo statement inline (2nd example), the variable is blank.

Answer (score 0):

The ' escape doesn't work in this case. The following works, escaping the $ character:

```
sudo su - oracle -s /bin/ksh -c "echo Called from sudo - Oracle home is \${ORACLE_HOME}"
```

So remove the ' and place \ in front of $